# I created an authentication api with express, what is the best way of consuming the api with Vuejs

Tags: node.js, api, vue.js, express, axios

I have an authentication api with nodejs and express fully working with ejs template. But I’d like to know how to use vuejs for the frontend instead of ejs

I already built the ui with Vuejs, then I created the api with nodejs/express and tested it with ejs.

I’m having issues with the authentication system using my vuejs ui, I can’t seem to call the api and persist form data properly.

Thanks

Comment: Run with a debugger. When something unexpected happens, either fix it or post the part of the code that isn't working here and describe the problem.